# Automatic Background Perl Execution on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell

I've been troubleshooting this issue for about a week and I am nowhere, so I wanted to reach out for some help.

I have a perl script that I execute via command like, usually in a manner of

```
 nohup ./script.pl --param arg --param2 arg2 &
```

I usually have about ten of these running at once to process the same type of data from different sources (that is specified through parameters). The script works fine and I can see logs for everything in nohup.out and monitor status via ps output. This script also uses a sql database to track status of various tasks, so I can track finishes of certain sources.

However, that was too much work, so I wrote a wrapper script to execute the script automatically and that is where I am running into problems. I want something exactly the same as I have, but automatic.

The getwork.pl script runs ps and parses output to find out how many other processes are running, if it is below the configured thresh it will query the database for the most out of date source and kick off the script.

The problem is that the kicked off jobs aren't running properly, sometimes they terminate without any error messages and sometimes they just hang and sit idle until I kill them.

The getwork script queries sql and gets the entire execution command via sql concatanation, so in the sql query I am doing something like CONCAT('nohup ./script.pl --arg ',param1,' --arg2 ',param2,' &') to get the command string.

I've tried everything to get these kicked off, I've tried using system (), but again, some jobs kick off, some don't, sometimes it gets stuck, sometimes jobs start and then die within a minute. If I take the exact command I used to start the job and run it in bash, it works fine.

I've tried to also open a pipe to the command like

```
open my $ca, "| $command" or die ($!);
print $ca $command;
close $ca;
```

That works just about as well as everything else I've tried. The getwork script used to be executed through cron every 30 minutes, but I scrapped that because I needed another shell wrapper script, so now there is an infinite look in the get work script that executes a function every 30 minutes.

I've also tried many variations of the execution command, including redirecting output to different files, etc... nothing seems to be consistent. Any help would be much appreciated, because I am truly stuck here....

EDIT: 
Also, I've tried to add separate logging within each script, it would start a new log file with it's PID ($$). There was a bunch of weirdness there too, all log files would get created, but then some of the processes would be running and writing to the file, others would just have an empty text file and some would just have one or two log entries. Sometimes the process would still be running and just not doing anything, other times it would die with nothing in the log. Me, running the command in shell directly always works though.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need a kind of job managing framework.

One of the bigest one is Gearman: http://www.slideshare.net/andy.sh/gearman-and-perl

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. The root issue here is execution of a process in a background with perl.